# Asus zenbook ux3402za no sound on ubuntu 22.4

Tags: sound, asus

There is no sound from the speakers or headphones on my asus ux3402za intel i1240P when hdmi is plugged in.
I tried many tutorials but it still doesn't work.

Comment: That's probably because the sound is playing on your external connected device.

Comment: Check in sound settings which is currently used output after you connected HDMI. It's likely that system automatically changes current audio output to HDMI audio.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with my new zenbook 3402. I tried some advice on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2476921&p=14107034#post14107034 but still no luck yet. it will be appreciated if anyone managess to solve this issue.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Any updates on this would be appreciated